# Transferir datos entre componentes

Tags: angular

Tengo un componente con un formulario que recoge ciertos datos y únicamente cuando los tiene y al pulsar el botón de submit, avanza hacia el siguiente componente, con otro formulario.
Estos componentes son hermanos, pertenecen a un módulo que he llamado 'agregar' que crea un objeto con muchos atributos diferenciados en 3 interfaces. Es decir, el objeto principal tiene dos atributos que a su vez tienen su propia interfaz.
La idea es pasar recoger los datos del primer atributo, enviarlos al siguiente componente que recogerá nuevos datos de otro atributo, para que una vez tenga ambos pueda enviarlos al último componente que también recoge datos y construye el objeto principal para ser guardado.

Mi carencia está en que no logro dar con la forma de transferir esos datos al pulsar el botón.
He probado a enviarlos como 'extras' al método navigateByUrl, pero seguramente no sea la mejor forma o los esté enviando/recogiendo de manera inadecuada.
Espero que se entienda la idea, muchas gracias de antemano por la ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

Ya he dado con la respuesta.

```
this.router.navigate(['/nuevo/distribucion'], { queryParams: this.ubicacion });
```

Y recojo los datos:

```
const data = this.route.snapshot.queryParams;
```

Originalmente estaba enviando los datos de manera errónea. Dejo la consulta por si a alguien le fuese de utilidad.